# Conditional Group and Select in LINQ with type conversion

Tags: c#, linq

I know there is a bunch of questions out there already on this but I still cannot get it to work due to the type conversion (I think).

I have a list of custom class and I normally group this either by months (mt) or by quarters (qr) depending on user choice. This works fine. However, now I have the request to allow grouping by say Q413 and the rest of 2013 in months. Mt and Qr are strings. Quartpos is a double and equals 4 if only Q4 is in quarters and rest in months.

Here is what I have:

```
List<MyClass> results = classlist
  .GroupBy(a => new { 
                a.rg,
                a.tar,
                a.mt = ((double.Parse(a.qr) < quartpos) ? a.mt : 0),
                a.qr })
  .Select(g => new MyClass { 
               RG = g.Select(a => a.rg).First(),
               tar = g.Select(a => a.tar).First(),
               yr = g.Select(a => a.yr).First(),
               qr = g.Select(a => a.qr).First(),
               mt = g.Select(a => a.mt).First(),
               pp = g.Average(a => double.Parse(a.pp)),
               pi = g.Sum(a => double.Parse(a.pi)),
               cp = g.Average(a => double.Parse(a.cp)),
               ci = g.Sum(a => double.Parse(a.ci)),
               it = g.Sum(a => double.Parse(a.it)),
               to = g.Sum(a => double.Parse(a.to)),
               cnt = g.Select(a => a.dt).Distinct().Count(),
               pdvol = g.Sum(a => (double.Parse(a.pp) <= 1) 
                                  ? 0 
                                  : (double.Parse(a.pi) / double.Parse(a.pp))) })
  .ToList();
```

This throws two errors:

1. String Int type conversion - since mt is string but : 0 is int
2. Invalid anonymous type member declaration.

I m fully aware that I would have to use the same syntax in the select to make sure that quarters are selected if grouped by quarters and months if grouped by mounths also.

Definition of the class:

```
public class Myclass
{
    public string yr;
    public string qr;
    public string mt;
    public string cw;
    public string tar;
    public string RG;
    public double pp;
    public double pi;
    public double cp;
    public double ci;
    public double it;
    public double to;
    public double pd;
    public double cd;
    public double fp;
    public double fi;
    public double fd;
    public int cnt;
    public double pdmw;
    public double pdvol;

}
```

`classlist` is a class where all variables are strings - straight from csv import.

My question is how can I group month (mt) conditionally?

Comment: Hi nik, it's hard to help you without knowing what is the type of classlist. Also, post the definition of the class MyClass

Comment: Why are you even storing month etc by string? `DateTime` would be better, even `integer` would be better, You should probably consider changing your property names to something more descriptive (but thats off topic). The down vote is probably because you haven't included a question, just a blog entry

Comment: @Sayse: they are strings because I import them from a csv and tried various things but parsing on import seems a lot slower than parsing after LINQ aggregation, because it is avery long list (1m rows) and after aggregation I need to do only a few parses

Comment: Fair enough, but I find it hard to believe, I'd imagine your csv import is a one time thing and I'd imagine you are using the dates multiple times.

Comment: Are you using an API or something that is imposing a limit on your variable name lengths?  If not, please use more descriptive variable names.  It'll make your code much much easier to read and maintain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One not very elegant solution I can think of is to split `classlist` into two new lists with a simple `.select(a => double.Parse(a.qr) < quartpos)` and then keep the code that does all the other stuff from above and group list1 by months and list2 by quarters. This would remove the need for conditional grouping.

But I thought there must be a better way.

```
        public static IEnumerable<EVFile> SmallerQ(this IEnumerable<EVFile> @this, double quarterpos)
    {
        return from ev in @this
               where (double.Parse(ev.qr)<quarterpos)
               select ev;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<EVFile> LargerEqQ(this IEnumerable<EVFile> @this, double quarterpos)
    {
        return from ev in @this
               where (double.Parse(ev.qr) >= quarterpos)
               select ev;
    }

newlist =  classlist.SmallerQ(quarterpos).ToList();
```

With these two extension methods I can split the original list in two and then proceed without the conditional group join. So it does the job, but as said not very nicely.

Answer (score 1):

```
a.mt = ((double.Parse(a.qr) < quartpos) ? a.mt : 0)
```

You can't create anonymous types like this. Take a look at the syntax in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx).

Either you want:

```
a.mt
```

or

```
PropertyName = ((double.Parse(a.qr) < quartpos) ? a.mt : 0)
```

in this line.